# Implementing a Conditional Logit in Python StatsModels

Tags: logistic, python, conditional-probability, statsmodels, pandas

I have a dataframe with some horseracing data, and each row contains a predicted speed rating for each of the runners. I am now trying to convert that information into a winning probability for each runner in a given race. I have tried implementing a softmax by group, but it tends to produce extreme results for the favored horse and is not well-calibrated to actual observed results. Much of the academic literature on the topic suggests using a conditional logit model for such a problem, but my attempts to implement it have thrown a variety of errors.

A simplified example of the dataframe that would be used to fit the conditional logit is below. The goal is to create a new column that provides a winning probability based on just the speed rating, conditional on the speed ratings of the other runners in the race.

| Race | Runner | Proj. Speed Rating | Winner? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1012 | Horse 1 | 87.25 | 0 |
| 1012 | Horse 2 | 86.52 | 0 |
| 1012 | Horse 3 | 77.56 | 0 |
| 1012 | Horse 4 | 84.25 | 1 |
| 1013 | Horse 1 | 77.55 | 0 |
| 1013 | Horse 3 | 74.06 | 0 |
| 1013 | Horse 5 | 74.59 | 1 |
| 1013 | Horse 7 | 74.46 | 0 |

My code thus far is as follows:

```
from statsmodels.discrete.conditional_models import ConditionalLogit

labels =  df['Winner?']
pred = df['Proj. Speed Rating']
groups = df['Race']

cl_model = ConditionalLogit(endog = labels, exog = pred,groups = group)
cl_fit = cl_model.fit()
cl_pred = cl_fit.predict(pred_external,race_external)
```

However no matter which adjustments I make the 'predict' line continues to throw a value error - in the format above it's 'Truth Value is ambiguous', and if I add the 'exog =' and 'groups =' it's a "NotImplemented" error. So my question is twofold: 1.) am I correct in thinking a conditional logit is the best way to approach this problem, even with only 1 independent variable? 2.) If so, how can I fix my code above to generate race-level probability estimates?

I don't have a statistics or computer science background, so any assistance with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the problem not here: cl_model = ConditionalLogit(endog = labels, exog = pred,**groups = group**) I believe you should have "group=groups" instead of "groups= group"

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything obviously wrong and the approach appears sound.  The simple simulation below emulates what you are doing and runs fine for me.  Note that if you construct and fit the model in separate steps, you can see whether the ValueError occurs during setup or during optimization.

```
from statsmodels.discrete.conditional_models import ConditionalLogit
import numpy as np

g = np.kron(np.arange(100), np.ones(5)).astype(int)
x = np.random.normal(size=500)
pr = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
y = (np.random.uniform(size=500) < pr).astype(int)

m = ConditionalLogit(endog=y, exog=x, groups=g)
r = m.fit()
```

Can you send the complete text of the ValueError?  Also, check the dtypes of the three variables, perhaps one of them is a string or object?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Following your suggestion I fixed the dtype of one of the inputs (it was previously a DF object), and can now get the 'fit' command to work. I'm now getting an error when I try to run 'predict' though - "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.." This time the dtypes are all floats/integers so I'm not sure if my parameters are correct, and I can't find any examples along these lines on the StatsModels site. I updated the code above, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Conditional logit models aren't very useful for prediction.  Each group (race for you) has a fixed effect and the model cannot extrapolate the results to new groups.  Even for the groups in your dataset the fixed effects are not explicitly estimated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I'm a bit confused on that point - what would be a typical use case for SM CL's 'predict' then? Or are you saying 'fit' model can be directly used on out-of-sample data? Since empirically the winning speed ratings are normally distributed, could we use random effects instead? Finally, if a CL model isn't ideal for this as you say, what would be your suggested method for converting a group of ratings into probabilities, besides a softmax? Sorry for all the questions; any thoughts on any of the above appreciated again.

Comment: The results of predict can be used to compare two horses that will run in the same race.  If you subtract the linear predictors for two observations in the same group, then this is the log-odds ratio comparing the success probabilities for those two observations.  Because you are subtracting, the common fixed effect (which is not estimated) cancels out.  But you cannot use these results to obtain an absolute probability for a single horse winning its race.

Comment: Would it be possible to compare more than two horses with this method? I'm not looking for absolute probabilities, just ones relative to the other group members. Thanks again for your response; I appreciate it.

Comment: As long as all the horses are in the same race then you can compare their estimated values as a set, e.g. you can rank the horses from highest to lowest probability of winning.

Comment: Yes, sorry if I wasn't clear before but that's what I've been trying to do from the start, just make comparisions between horses in the same race.  How can I fix my code above so that the "predict" line generates those values for each set? Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think any change is needed.  Just avoid converting the predicted values from the conditional logit model to the log-odds scale.  As long as you only take differences between log-odds within the same race you are fine.

Comment: Typo above: you should avoid converting predicted values from the conditional logit model to the _absolute probability_ scale.

Comment: Thanks Kerby - what I meant is that I keep getting value errors when calling 'predict'. Is there any chance you can edit your answer above to include another line after the 'fit', so that I can make sure I'm entering the parameters correctly?

Comment: On Statsmodels 0.12.2 I get a NotImplementedError not a ValueError when I run either `m.predict(r.params)` or `r.predict()`.  But you can get the equivalent result by running `np.dot(xx, r.params)`, where `xx` is the design matrix that you want to predict on.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the NotImplemented was a type of Value error, I get the same message. I assume that's an issue on StatModels' end then? And thanks, what would be the 'xx' in the matrix, just the speed ratings after using a GroupBy for each race?